# Why won't anyone accept public fields in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, field, public

Seems like every C# static analyzer wants to complain when it sees a public field. But why? Surely there are cases where a public (or internal) *field* is enough, and there is no point in having a property with its `get_` and `set_` methods? What if I know for sure that I won't be redefining the field or adding to it (side effects are bad, right?) - shouldn't a simple field suffice?

Comment: Simple fields are better in some cases, especially where objects are serialized across an application level protocol (as XML lets say). Saying this is "wrong" is an opinion... the entire Java language existed without the concept of a property at all. Personally, I write public fields all the time, and have never seen them break when refactoring that 1 in 100 odball case into a property. The only scenario I can think of where is might make an issue is if you are accessing the fields\properties with reflection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Property and Field in C# .NET 3.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because it breaks encapsulation -- this is why most people use accessors heavily.  However, if you think it's the right solution for your task, ignore it (meaning the strict encapsulation complaints) and do what's right for your project.  Don't let the OO nazis tell you otherwise.

Comment: Um, wtf? Are you saying that accessors provide encapsulation? o_O

Comment: That's their aim.  Accessors encapsulate the inner workings of the object from the outside.

Comment: Encapsulation is information hiding. With a public field you can do foo.bar=baz, with a public property you can do foo.bar=baz. Seeing that there's no difference in syntax and in contract, accessors do not hide information.

Comment: So if you have a property transparently fetch/store data in a database, that isn't encapsulation just because it's accessible from the outside?  I think you need to recheck your definition of encapsulation...

Comment: Shouldn't a database fetch be a *method*, not a *property get*?

Comment: Dmitri, Not necessarily, but it was just an example.  For what it's worth, property gets/sets are really just methods, and although it may not be a good idea to do queries in them in most cases, there's no reason this is an inherently Bad Thing (TM).

Comment: Cody, accessors that do more than handle a member field clearly do hide information. That doesn't apply to the vast majority of accessors though - they are not in any way encapsulation, they merely model the machine's limitations. Encapsulating accessors are the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Iraimbilanja, even ignoring that many accessors simply backend to a field, saying they don't provide encapsulation is nonsense.  If you want to change how the data is handled internally, accessors allow you to do that.  How is that not encapsulation?

Comment: Accessors provide a level of indirection. Most times you'll just see get; set;, but there are times that you really need to hide internal details. If you use Accessors first, you don't have to add a crapload of code. If you don't, you're going to have to, or something will break.

Comment: Point taken. When taking into account future maintenance and how it requires to have implementation information, accessors do provide encapsulation. I'm only unsure where people who read your answer interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Encapsulation is not hiding information. Encapsulation is hiding *implementation*. The idea is that as a client of the object you don't want to care how its properties are stored, may them be via backing fields, via access to other aggregated objects, via direct access to the database (no matter how absurd this might seem). Properties provide precisely that abstraction layer. They also allow very practical things such as validations.

Answer (score 27):

It's really about future-proofing your code.  When you say (emphasis mine):

> **What if I know for sure** that I won't
>   be redefining the field or adding to
>   it (side effects are bad, right?) -
>   shouldn't a simple field suffice?

That's an absolute statement, and as we know (as well as most static analyzers), there are only two absolutes in life.

It's just trying to protect you from that.  If it is an issue, you should be able to tell the analyzer to ignore it (through attributes that are dependent on the analysis tool you are using).

Comment: Languages like Python and C# allow classes to have properties with getters and setters, but are accessed and mutated as normal public fields.  EX: `myInstance.someField = 42;`.  In Java, you're *definitely* setting a field.  Bad.  But in Python or C#, you could be using a setter under the hood.  So if one can easily change from a public field to a public getter **without breaking dependent code**, then isn't the "no public fields" rule not so hard-and-fast?

Comment: @kdbanman Even though the syntax looks the same, [changing from a field to a property is a breaking change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863182/changing-fields-to-property-is-a-breaking-change-under-what-scenarios).

Answer (score 21):

Given the fact that current C# 3.0 allows for automatic properties whose syntax is like:

```
public int Property {get; set;}
```

the extra work required for using Properties over public fields is almost zero. The thing is you can never be completely sure a field won't be used differently or the accessor won't ever change and given the trade off in work there's no reason not to implement a property.

Anyway, the analyzer complains about things that in a high percentage (in this case like 99.99% of the cases) are bad programming practices... but anyway it is just complaining. Fields can be made public and there are some extreme cases where its direct use may be justified. As ever, **use your common sense**... but keep in mind the elemental rule for best programming practices ... **Is there a really good reason to break the convention?** If there's then go ahead, if not or if the answer is "it involves more work" then stick to the practice...

Comment: I've actually run into one case where it was expedient to make a public field: exposing a counter for Interlocked.Increment, which needs a genuine ref. Even then, I could have instead exposed my own Increment method, so it wasn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: Another situation where fields behave differently from properties is with structure types.  If `f` is a field of type `Rectangle`, and `p` is a property of the same type, an access to `thing.f.Width` will simply be a direct integer access, while reading `thing.p.Width` will require making a copy of `p` (all four fields therein), and then accessing the `Width` field of that property.

Answer (score 9):

Because changing public fields later to have get/set accessors will break code.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340528/c-automatic-properties-why-do-i-have-to-write-get-set#340682) for more information

Answer (score 4):

In general, it's a good idea to hide fields behind properties, even if you "know for sure" that you won't be redefining the field.  All too often, what you "know for sure" today changes tomorrow.  And, making a property to refer to a field is just a little bit of trouble.

That said, static analyzers are no substitute for thought.  If you're happy with your design and in your judgement the analyzer is wrong, then ignore or (if possible) suppress that warning in that circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that generally you don't know for sure that you won't be redefining the field or adding to it later. The whole point of encapsulating and hiding the data is that you are then free to do these things without changing the public interface and subsequently breaking dependent classes. If your property accessors are just simple get/sets then they'll be compiled down to that anyway, so ther are no performance concerns - given this your question should be is there any good reason not to use them?

Answer (score 1):

One other benefit properties bring to the table is when doing Reflection. When you reflect over your class, you can get all the properties in one shot, rather than having to get the properties AND the fields.

Answer (score 0):

And let's not forget that accessors give you flexibility when working with multiple threads.

Comment: Fields can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, `Interlocked.Increment`, and the like.  Properties can't.  If a type has an `Int32` property but doesn't include any methods to perform interlocked operations upon it, many kinds of thread-safe code will be impossible.