# Some Logical OOP Concepts

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a question.

```
class A
{
    static void m1()
    {
       int x=10;
    }
}

class B
{
    // if i want to access the variable x in b class how can i access it 

    A a = new A();
    // a. what should i write here to access x variable
}
```

Comment: What is "call A"? Not valid C#, certainly.

Comment: i want to know how can i access some public methods variable in some  other class or in the same class

Comment: or mehods variables have scop limited to the methods only so we can not access them....

Comment: I want to know what "call" means.

Comment: You cannot access a variable declared in a method from any other place than the method itself. It is scoped within the method. If you want the variable to be accessible from outsede the method you need to make it a class level field.

Comment: And please either give concrete examples wherever applicable. the one you have given creates more confusion than clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access `x` you must make it a field on `A`:

```
class A
{
    public int X;
}
class B
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.X = 17;
    }
}
```

However it is generally bad practice to expose public fields from a class - it is better to wrap the field in a property to encapsulate it:

```
class A
{
    int _x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; }
    }
}
```

If this syntax seems cumbersome you can simplify it a bit.  C# has a feature called *automatically implemented properties* in which the compiler will generate the code above for you if you do this:

```
class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sir what is default type for property, is it private or public?

Comment: By default all members on a class are `private`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be either property or a public variable.

Comment: are properties always public or we hav to explicitly declare them public and by default they are private?

Comment: Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Class1
    {
        public int x;

        public void M1()
        {
            x = 10;
        }

    }

class ClassB
{

void Method()
{
    Class1 a = new Class1();
    a.M1();
    a.x = 5;
    //at this point the x will contain 5
}
}
```

The exmaple uses instance variables , not static.

To access static variables you must have a static method M1 then in ClassB you access the x variable usign the class name not the object name, like this:

```
Class1.x = 5;
```

Variable x1 must also be declared as static like: public static x = 10;

Answer (score 1):

First, when asking a question, please spend just 30 seconds trying to get it *right*. Your code is nonsense.

`call` isn't a valid keyword in C#. Did you mean `class`? Or something else? Second, is it unreasonable to ask you to run the text through a spell checker? None of us are getting paid to answer your questions, we're doing it for free, in our own free time. So if you want answers, make it *easy* for us to understand and answer your questions. Don't be lazy at our expense, because then we'll be lazy too, and ignore your question.

Now, as I understand your question, you can't. `x` is a local variable declared inside the function. It's not visible anywhere else.

Comment: ok sir i am sorry, i will do the same told by you ...thanks for our answer