# Is there a way to access the columns in a Dapper FastExpando via string or index?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I am pulling in a `Dapper FastExpando` object and want to be able to reference the column names dynamically at run time rather than at design/compile time.  So I want to be able to do the following:

```
var testdata = conn.Query("select * from Ride Where RiderNum = 21457");
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
foreach( var row in testdata) {
    var Value = row["PropertyA"];
}
```

I understand that I can do:

```
var Value = row.PropertyA;
```

but I can't do that since the name of the property i'm going to need won't be known until runtime.

The answer from [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-dynamic-property-via-string) doesn't work.  I still get the same `Target Invocation` exception.  So...

**Is there any way to do what I want to do with a Dapper FastExpando?**

Comment: While the chosen answer wouldn't work for "this SO Question", there was an answer on that question that would.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-dynamic-property-via-string/5738983#5738983

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sure, it is actually way easier than that:

```
var sql = "select 1 A, 'two' B";
var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)connection.Query(sql).First();
row["A"].IsEqualTo(1);
row["B"].IsEqualTo("two");
```

Comment: I find myself always using `FirstOrDefault()` and still having to check if row is null first before trying to access the row index. Is there a way to try and fetch a column value or a specific row, or return a default value if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the portion of the title "or index?" - I needed to access results by index since the column names being returned changed sometimes, so you can use a variation of Sam Saffron's answer like this:

```
var sql = "select 1, 'two'";
var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)connection.Query(sql).First();
row.Values.ElementAt(0).IsEqualTo(1);
row.Values.ElementAt(1).IsEqualTo("two");
```

Answer (score 1):

There a simple way to access fields direct below sample

```
string strConexao = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;

conexaoBD = new SqlConnection(strConexao);
conexaoBD.Open();

var result = conexaoBD.Query("Select Field1,Field2 from Table").First();

//access field value result.Field1 
//access field value result.Field2

if (result.Field1 == "abc"){ dosomething}
```