# OrderBy, ObservableCollection<dynamic>, ICompare

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to sort an Observable collection of dynamic objects. I tried implementing IComparer but it tells me that I cannot implement a dynamic interface. I'm stuck now. Any ideas how to acomplish this?

I tried this

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x, new DynamicSerializableComparer());
```

and then the IComparer

```
public class DynamicSerializableComparer : IComparer<dynamic>
        {
            string _property;

            public DynamicSerializableComparer(string property)
            {
                _property = property;
            }

            public int Compare(dynamic stringA, dynamic stringB)
            {
                string valueA = stringA.GetType().GetProperty(_property).GetValue();
                string valueB = stringB.GetType().GetProperty(_property).GetValue();

                return String.Compare(valueA, valueB);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Just implement the non-generic version IComparer

Answer (score 0):

`IComparer<dynamic>` is, at compile time, the same as `IComparer<object>`. [That's why you can't implement it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2009/02/04/c-dynamic-part-vii.aspx)

Try implementing `IComparer<object>` instead, and casting to dynamic.

```
public class DynamicSerializableComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    string _property;

    public DynamicSerializableComparer(string property)
    {
        _property = property;
    }

    public int Compare(object stringA, object stringB)
    {
        string valueA = stringA.GetType().GetProperty(_property).GetValue();
        string valueB = stringB.GetType().GetProperty(_property).GetValue();

        return String.Compare(valueA, valueB);
    }

}
```

Comment: This implementation won't work if the objects are actually dynamic (like `ExpandoObject` or some object coming from IronPython).

Comment: Because `Type.GetProperty()` won't give you dynamic properties. `Type` doesn't know anything about `dynamic` or DLR (I think).

Comment: @Svick: I don't think you're right.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-dynamic-property-via-string

Comment: @EricJ., that question is about anonymous objects, which are not dynamic. It really doesn't work with types like `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: In addition to svick's comment: how should IComparer be able to compare a dynamic, when a dynamic can be nearly anything

Comment: @Michael9000: Because it's using reflection. You can't do it with ExpandoObject, because it's a DynamicObject itself...