# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types in linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, object, casting, dbnull

```
var gFieldList = new List<string>() { "Supplier", "Country" };
    var sFieldList = new List<string>() { "Sales"};

     var gField = string.Join(", ", gFieldList.Select(x => "it[\"" + x + "\"] as " + x));
     var sField = string.Join(", ", sFieldList.Select(y => "Sum(Convert.ToDouble(it[\""+y+"\"])) as "+y));


         var newSort = dataTable
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .GroupBy("new("+gField+")", "it")
                        .Select("new("+sField+",it.Key as Key, it as Data)");

var groupedData = (from dynamic dat in newSort select dat).ToList();
```

throwing exception

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

in the last line,

```
var groupedData = (from dynamic dat in newSort select dat).ToList();
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: newSort is var type, where in I'm getting value from a Dynamic Linq Expression.

Comment: Could you share the `var newSort =` line?

Comment: yes sure, I'll edit the question and add this line. thanks.

Comment: @VarunChaturvedi can the values in dataTable be DBNull?

Comment: The values in the dataTable are coming from the Excel files, so the values can be blank there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2:** try change your Convert like this

```
sFieldList.Select(y => "Sum(Convert.ToDouble(iif(it[\""+y+"\"] == @0,0,it[\""+y+"\"]))) as "+y)
```

and then

```
var newSort = dataTable
                .AsEnumerable()
                .AsQueryable()
                .GroupBy("new("+gField+")", "it")
                .Select("new("+sField+",it.Key as Key, it as Data)",DBNull.Value);
```

**UPDATE2:** for round Sum result try this:

```
sFieldList.Select(y => "Sum(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(iif(it[\""+y+"\"] == @0,0,it[\""+y+"\"])),2)) as "+y)
```

Comment: none of them seems to be working, both of them throwing the same exception..!

Comment: @VarunChaturvedi you can specify which namespace are used that extension GroupBy and Select? Is used  3rd party library?

Comment: I used System.Linq.Dynamic;

Comment: Bingo.! it works..!! thanks a lot Grundy! can you help me with one more question I posted a day before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513663/how-can-i-access-the-result-of-dynamic-linq-with-dynamic-key-value-pairs-of-ienu

Comment: any idea how can I round of the result of Sum above to 2 decimal digits?

Comment: @VarunChaturvedi use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: am not able to embedd with this dynamic query, should I use Math.Round in the dounble quotes itself like Sum()?

Comment: exactly, I used it this way only, but it says **Argument types do not match**

Comment: @VarunChaturvedi you right, it because Sum function in dynamic linq don't retun value `void Sum(decimal selector);`

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658343/how-to-set-round-of-the-result-of-aggregate-function-used-in-dynamic-linq-query/19674780

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var gFieldList = new List<string ?>() { "Supplier", "Country" };
var sFieldList = new List<string ?>() { "Sales"};
```

Comment: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'

Comment: you should be put Where condition to check Null.