# object' does not contain a definition for MainTypeCode for dynamic data

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

This below query return some mock data for unit testing.

```
var colorsList = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)colorsRepository.GetColorsList().Result;
```

It given the result as dynamic object

[image]

I want to get `MainTypeCode` value only. But it is showing **object' does not contain a definition for MainTypeCode**

```
colorsList.Select(cl => (dynamic)cl.MainTypeCode);
```

### Edit:

> And let me know how to arrange  dummy/mock dynamic data to execute the query?

and `colorsRepository.GetColorsList().Result;` is returning below way. Shall I change the mock data to run the query?

```
 public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetColorsList()
        {
            List<dynamic> colours = new List<dynamic>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                colours.Add((dynamic)new
                {
                    MainTypeCode = 1,
                    DoorCode = "001"
                });
            }
            return colours.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Comment: You should not use `Task.Result`. Either use `await colorsRepository.GetColorsList()` or `colorsRepository.GetColorsList().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: Guys can you tell me. How to arrange a dummy data for that query?

Comment: @How to set mock data for this `GetColorsList()` method?

Comment: I think you will have to use reflection in order to get the dynamic properties.

Comment: If `colorsList` is really `IEnumerable<dynamic>` - `colorsList.Select(cl => cl.MainTypeCode)` should work fine and not produce any compile time errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, the issue might be related with the dynamic. Could you try something like the following?

```
var colorLists = new [] { new {DoorCode = "001", MainTypeCode = 1}, new {DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode = 2}};
var mainTypeCodes = colorLists.Select(cl => cl.GetType().GetProperty("MainTypeCode").GetValue(cl, null));
```

[Get value of c# dynamic property via string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-sharp-dynamic-property-via-string)

Comment: your mock data should be able to be used with this query, could you try?

Comment: I want to set a mock data for my query. I don't want to change the query . Sorry

Comment: ah okay... so what you are trying to do is creating a unit test for it, and you are currently mocking up the colorsRepository, the GetColorsList method?

Comment: The one that I'm not too sure is how are you injecting the mock colorRepository object as the way your mock-up data seems valid to be queried upon (and your original query should work too). The one I wonder now is the colorRepository.GetColorLists().Result -- suggesting that GetColorLists() should return a task -- but then again, you wouldn't be able to go that far into getting exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161212/discussion-between-hsoesanto-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I have much time to elaborate a better answer, but you will have to use reflection in order to get the dynamic properties.

If you know the dynamic properties before hand you can try to do a class and create a Map method with reflection to get the object.