# How to use Enum's in a foreach loop where the Enum represents a property field and acts as counter (Months)?

Tags: c#

I need to generate some hour accounts if they don't exist and tried to make the method as easy as possible. Unfortunately I'm stuck at the following.

This is how I would check / create an account for every month:

```
// January

if (!_db.Stundenkonto.Any(x => x.MitarbeiterId == mitarbeiterId && x.Jahr == jahr && x.Monat == 1))     
{
  HrsAccount acc = new HrsAccount 
  {
    AccountId = new Guid(),
    UserId = loggedInUser,
    Month = 1 <<--- This is where I'd need the number of the Enum (1),
    HoursToWork = model.data[0].january <<--- Here I'd need the name of the Enum
    HoursWorked = model.data[1].january <<-- Same here
  }
}
```

So as you can see I need number AND value of the Enum. I tried:

```
foreach (MonthEnum month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MonthEnum)))
{
    HrsAccount acc = new HrsAccount 
  {
    AccountId = new Guid(),
    UserId = loggedInUser,
    Month = (double)month,
    HoursToWork = model.data[0].month <<-- Gives errors
    HoursWorked = model.data[1].month <<-- on these two
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get this working as I need it?

Edit: Sorry here is the Enum:

```
public enum MonthEnum
{
    january = 1,
    february,
    march,
    april,
    may,
    june,
    july,
    august,
    september,
    oktober,
    november,
    december
}
```

`model.data` are 4 arrays. They are all the same except one holds the hours the employee has to work, the other one how much the employee worked. The others are just calculations of those so they look like this:

`model.data[0]`: <<-- Hours he has to work

```
january: 60,
february: 120,
january: 120
march: 175,
april: 165,
may: 176,
june: 186,
july: 176,
august: 176,
september: 140,
october: 120,
november: 110,
december: 146
```

`model.data[1]` <<-- how much he actually worked

`model.data[2]` <<-- how many hrs were paid

`model.data[3]` <<-- difference between hrs he should work and hrs he worked

`model.data[4]` <<-- difference last month

Comment: What is `model.data[0].january`? Or what do you want it to be?

Comment: Please show us the full type of `model.data`.

Comment: Is `MonthEnum` an enum numbered from 1..12? And is model.Data an array indexed from 0..1?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Are`model.data[0]` - `model.data[4]`  integers?

Comment: @linuxrocks yeah each value of each property is an integer

Comment: What datatype is the model.Data? Some sort of dynamic?

Comment: I just re-checked and noticed they're doubles

@JanneMaitkainen doubles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your classes look like this:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    // Other parts of the class
    public DataClass[] data;
    // Other parts of the class
}

public class DataClass
{
    public int january;
    ...
    public int december;
}
```

I would say the easiest way to make them accessible like you wish would be to change the `data` class to something like

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int[12] hoursByMonth;
}
```

This way you could access them by month index and not by name:

```
foreach (MonthEnum month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MonthEnum)))
{
    HrsAccount acc = new HrsAccount 
    {
        AccountId = new Guid(),
        UserId = loggedInUser,
        Month = (int)month,
        HoursToWork = model.data[0].hoursByMonth[((int)month) - 1],
        HoursWorked = model.data[1].hoursByMonth[((int)month) - 1]
    }
}
```

In case this is not possible, maybe something I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4939508/9833095) might help

```
string enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(MonthEnum), month);
HoursToWork = model.data[0].GetType().GetField(enumName).GetValue(model.data[0]);
```

**EDIT**
To fix your error you could try this

```
HoursToWork = double.Parse(model.data[0].GetType().GetField(enumName).GetValue(model.data[0]).ToString());
```

Note however, that if the string for some reason can't be parsed, it will throw an exception. This fixes that:

```
foreach (MonthEnum month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MonthEnum)))
{
    double hoursToWork;
    double hoursWorked;
    string enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(MonthEnum), month);
    bool x = double.TryParse(model.data[0].GetType().GetField(enumName).GetValue(model.data[0]).ToString(), out hoursToWork);
    bool y = double.TryParse(model.data[0].GetType().GetField(enumName).GetValue(model.data[1]).ToString(), out hoursWorked);

    // If either of the TryParse fails, don't create a model due to false Data
    if(!x || !y) continue;

    HrsAccount acc = new HrsAccount
    {
        AccountId = new Guid(),
        UserId = loggedInUser,
        Month = (int)month,
        HoursToWork = hoursToWork,
        HoursWorked = hoursWorked
    };
}
```

**EDIT 2**
`.GetField(enumName)` has to be swapped for `.GetProperty(enumName)` depending on whether what you're trying to access is a field or a property.

Comment: Note that a `Dictionary<MonthEnum, int>` might be nicer to work with than a `int[12]`. Less prone to error if e.g. some people don't work every month.

Comment: @IDarkCoder Thanks for the reply! I didn't want to change the structure so I tried your last suggestion. This gives me the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'double'".
Looks like I need to change it after all. 
Need to read up on Dictionaries because I pretty much liked the suggestion from Flater above

Comment: @rawk I updated the answer to adapt to the converting error. My bad for that

Comment: @IDarkCoder Thank you so much!! I couldn't get this working at first and spent some time debugging. I realized that when using .GetField(enumName) did not work because the compiler created a field called <january>k_backingfield.
After some research I found out that when using .GetProperty(enumName) works as this reflects the actual name. Made my day. Thanks again :)

Comment: @rawk I forgot to mention that. I updated the answer to make it obvious for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to get the name of the current enum value?
You can do this using https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), 3)
```

Further you can use following to get the represented integer value:

```
var x = (int)MyEnum.AAAA;
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I got it but if you want to take a look at the updated question, you will see that I need to use the enum value to access the property of my model.data[x].

I found it difficult to explain sorry :|