# How to resolve variable in Linq Query c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have the below dynamic array

```
dynamic[] queueList = await queueInfo.Run.GetData<dynamic[]>(Name);
```

[image]

I want to get the unique values present in ImportTableName field. So, after some search I found this,

```
var distNames = queueList.Select(o => new {o.ImportTableName }).Distinct();
```

[image]

which works as expected.

But I don't want to hard code the fieldname "ImportTableName". So tried doing something like this

```
dynamic[] queueList = await queueInfo.Run.GetData<dynamic[]>(Name);
string tableName = "ImportTableName"
var distNames = queueList.Select(o => new {o.tableName }).Distinct();
```

But it doesn't work, result is just NULL. Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: The second way you tried that is hard coded not the first one which worked. In first method that is property of that class and second one is hard-coded string.

Comment: @TechYogesh - I think I did not explain it properly, it is not always "ImportTableName", it can be anything.

Comment: Dynamic select https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select than just a `Distinct` after that.

Comment: Dynamic is not a good fit when you don't know the property names at compile time. Have you considered storing your data in dictionaries instead?

Comment: In order to answer this, we need to know how the dynamic objects are generated inside the GetData method. Using reflection works for regular .Net objects assigned to a dynamic reference, but not for e.g. ExpandoObjects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-sharp-dynamic-property-via-string

Comment: what is the result of queueList.Select(o => o.GetType()) ?

Comment: @alexqc - it returns `{Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is array of `JObject`, which has indexer, you can apply it to each element to get value of desired field:

```
var distNames = queueList.Select(x => x[tableName]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But its not working, `property` is null.

Comment: Try `GetField` instead of `GetProperty`, I did not know what is `ImportTableName` exactly.

Comment: It is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: Also `queueList.Select(o => o.GetType())` gives me `{Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"}`

Comment: If it is JSON, you can simply cast it to `JObject` and then `GetValue` of property with `tableName` name. Look at updated answer.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
    dynamic[] queueList = new dynamic[]{new { id = 1, ImportTableName = "Data"}};

    string propName = "ImportTableName";    
    var distNames = queueList.Select(d => d.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(d, null)).Distinct();
```

It returns as expected "Data".

Comment: It works for your example, but it doesn't work on my code. Note, `GetData` returns `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`