# an "addOn" to VS 2010 , a class to show properties in the intellisense drop down / snippest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, intellisense

In code below, when you access the style property, 
I want it to be accepting parameter-type: top, left, width etc...
so it'll be inserted from intellisense firstly not to give you a chance 
to accidentally misspell, forget or just for the sake of "automation" or however we call it, to be in the intellisense as an option to select from.

Instead of:

```
objectID.Style.Add("property", "Value");
```

you get offered by the available properties:

```
objectID.Style.Add(Top, "here you will hardcode manually"); 
objectID.Style.Add(Left, "100px");
objectID.Style.Add(Width, "230px"); // but every parameter that represents an object property 
        //such as: Top, Left Etc' ... i would like to have it as an option opposed, to hard coding it
```

I will be happy to give more detailed ideas of what I was thinking of... 
**with another example:**

```
    DateTime fullDate = DateTime.Now;
    string ddays = fullDate.Day.ToString();
    string dmonth = fullDate.Month.ToString();
    string dyear = fullDate.Year.ToString();
```

How can I, with the code above, that takes parts of date and stores each into a string 
representing the date, Day, Month, Year 
Then to put it in a class so I can reuse it on other codes:

```
Label1.Text = Day; Label2.Text = Month; Label3.Text = Year;
```

Again what I want to achieve is that those values will be inside intellisense
when ever the App_Code has the so called "Class" we have built...

Same as with the style properties in first part of that thread.

As I am new to oop I would like to better comprehend from that example 
what are field properties Types (your own) and classes, from this perspective too (those codes above)
I will really appreciate the right / detailed answer, with hope that one day, I would be able to help others too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first example, an enum is perfect:

```
public enum StyleOptions { Top, Left, Width, etc }

objectID.Style.Add(StyleOptions.Top, "here you will hardcode manually");
```

For the second one, I'd recommend passing around a `DateTime` instead of separate `string`s.  If you then want to show the separate parts in separate labels, then in the page/form/user control that has the boxes, do your `Label1.Text = fullDate.Day.ToString();` (etc.) code.

`DateTime` (a `struct`) and `StyleOptions` (an `enum`) are both types.  `class`es are also types, (and are the most common types you'll see in C#) but I'm not sure which classes you're using here (whatever contains the methods where you've got your code snippets is almost certainly a class you've made).  Fields are essentially variables that belong to instances of types (if non-static), or to the type itself (if static).  Properties are accessed like fields, but are defined using methods, so you can do things like lazy-loading and notify when properties changed on get and set.  If that's not too clear, see [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp), and [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) and [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw) documentation.

Comment: i would like to thank the kind answer of Mr Tim S.
although i didn't yet understand i'll go through that code , i'll implement it, read your post again ... then hopfully better comprehend ... Thanks a lot ppl!