# Setting properties from one class to another via GetProperties

Tags: c#, .net

here is a simple example to clear my intentions.

```
class A {
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public string Hash
    public C c
}
class B {
    public int id
    public string name
    public C c
}
class C {
    public string name
}
var a = new A() { Id = 123, Name = "something", Hash = "somehash" };
var b = new B();
```

I want to set `b`'s properties from `a`. I have tried something but no luck.

```
public void GenericClassMatcher(object firstModel, object secondModel)
    {
        if (firstModel != null || secondModel != null)
        {
            var firstModelType = firstModel.GetType();
            var secondModelType = secondModel.GetType();
            // to view model
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in firstModelType.GetProperties())
            {
                var firstModelPropName = prop.Name.ElementAt(0).ToString().ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + prop.Name.Substring(1); // lowercase first letter
                if (prop.PropertyType.FullName.EndsWith("Model"))
                {
                    GenericClassMatcher(prop, secondModelType.GetProperty(firstModelPropName));
                }
                else
                {
                    var firstModelPropValue = prop.GetValue(firstModel, null);
                    var secondModelProp = secondModelType.GetProperty(firstModelPropName);
                    if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "Guid")
                    {
                        firstModelPropValue = firstModelPropValue.ToString();
                    }
                    secondModelProp.SetValue(secondModel, firstModelPropValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What shall I do?

Comment: You need to enumerate fields as well as properties. (`type.GetFields()`). The example classes you've shown have only fields.

Comment: I have added a property also.

Comment: not related to the main problem but i think you should replace this `if (firstModel != null || secondModel != null)` 
by `if (firstModel != null && secondModel != null)`

Comment: That isn't a property, a property is `MyProperty {get;set;}`. [Difference between Property and Field in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/653536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to *map* one class to another.  [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is the best tool I've come across to do this.

```
public class A 
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public string Hash;
        public C c;
    }

    public class B 
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public C c;
    }

    public class C 
    {
        public string name;
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A() { Id = 123, Name = "something", Hash = "somehash" };
            var b = new B();

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();

            b = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<A, B>(a);


            Console.WriteLine(b.id);
            Console.WriteLine(b.name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need a conversion of the field name before mapping.

Comment: @fastreload I can't tell what conversion you need to make based on your question, but AutoMapper can handle it.

Comment: There is good lambda syntax for that in AutoMapper. Working on a sample for you.

Comment: Wow! well, capitalization differences work out of the box with AutoMapper, see above edit.

Comment: Wow! That made me cry. Thanks!