# How to get value of inherited property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get inherited property value using reflection? 
I try with `BindingFlags` but still trigger `NullReferenceException`

```
object val = targetObject.GetType().GetProperty("position", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(targetObject, null);
```

`position` is iherited public property and has a declared value.

**EDIT:**

```
class myParent
{
    public float[] position;
    public myParent()
    {
        this.position = new float[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}

class myChild : myParent
{
    public myChild() : base() { }
}

myChild obj = new myChild();
PropertyInfo p = obj.GetType().GetProperty("position", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

I tried with several combinations with BindingFlags but `p` always is null :( ,

Comment: Could you post Class which contains inherited property?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use the overload with `BindingFlags` you have to explicitly specify all the flags what you are interested.

Also note that: (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx))

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static
>   in order to get a return.

```
object val = targetObject.GetType()
             .GetProperty("position", 
                          BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | 
                          BindingFlags.Instance | 
                          BindingFlags.Public)
             .GetValue(targetObject, null);
```

EDIT:

You have a `position` **field** not a **property** !.

(A good place to start learning the difference: [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5) especially this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/653799/872395))

Change your `position` to a property:

```
public float[] position { get; set; }
```

Or you use the `targetObject.GetType().GetField(...` method to retrieve the field.

Answer (score 3):

```
BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
```

works only for static members. Be sure to specify

```
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public
```

and you should get inherited properties.