# How to check that a certificate was applied in a named HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have registered a named HttpClient in my app.  I would like to add a test before i use this client to ensure that it has the certificate applied.

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToCert, passwordToCert);

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);

services.AddHttpClient(name, client =>
     {
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(hostName);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
     }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => handler)
       .UseHttpClientMetrics()
       .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)) //Set lifetime to five minutes
       .AddPolicyHandler(RetryPolicy.GetRetryPolicy());
```

The issue is I cant seem to find it anywhere in the client object that says it has the message handler.

```
_client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(_settings.Name);
```

[image]

I dont seem to have access to any of the parameters that start with _

Comment: With the default HttpClient it will not work, because there is no public accessible property/method to receive the HttpClientHandler. You can write your own class, which holds the HttpClient and the Handler/Cert seperatly. But I am not sure, if it's possible to add it as named HttpClient then

Comment: yeah i was afraid of that.  I have four separate httpclients being registered it was easer having them named.   The only other option i could come up with is catching the unauthorized error after the request has been sent.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, please specify whats missing

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible out of the box, but you can use the [FieldInfo.class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?view=net-6.0) from `System.Reflections` to get the needed information:

```
_client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(_settings.Name);
var handler = _client.BaseType.GetField("_handler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(_client) as HttpClientHandler;
```

With that procedure, you should be able to get the other fields, which are not accessable by default, too. You just need to make sure, from which class/type the property is from.

Comment: I'm getting this error:'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetField' and the best extension method overload 'TypeExtensions.GetField(Type, string, BindingFlags)' requires a receiver of type 'System.Type'CS1929

Comment: @MikeF What version of .Net do you use?

Comment: @MikeF From your error message i assume, that you are missing the BindingFlags. If not, please create a new question with your specific problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, because the one above did not work for me.

```
var handler = (HttpClientHandler)typeof(HttpClient).BaseType.GetField("_handler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(client);
```

Partially helped by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330249/how-to-get-value-of-inherited-property-using-reflection?rq=3)