# Why do we use fields & properties instead of just a variable?

Tags: c#, properties, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)
>   [Difference between Property and Field in C# .NET 3.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

I have seen that in c# the following pattern is common:

```
   private string m_name = string.Empty;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    set
    {
        m_name = value;
    }
}
```

why do we use a field and a property to hold a value when we can use a simple variable?
why should I use fields and properties instead of a simple variable?

Comment: See the wide range of answers in the above question

Comment: It depends on what you want to pre-process the value. Imagine if you (for some reason) wanted to make sure any string saved as Name contained at least 1 'e', you could do all the logic in the setter instead of in the main code body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for encapsulation principle. For hinding concrete implementaiton, and plus, you have an opportunity (in this case) to add additional code inside `get/set`.

If you don't need addittional code, you can use just

```
public string Name{get;set;}
```

or use fileds, as you would like. But using properties is a **guideline** offered by Microsoft.

So basically all, follow it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons for this, but 2 come to mind right away:

First, a property can be easily bound to a  control or other reflection-based controls that read all properties (rather than fields).

Second, there may be actions that you want to perform in getters or setters (such as firing a [NotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event).

Answer (score 0):

Properties provide the opportunity to protect a field in a class by reading and writing to it through the property. In other languages, this is often accomplished by programs implementing specialized getter and setter methods. C# properties enable this type of protection while also letting you access the property just like it was a field.

Another benefit of properties over fields is that you can change their internal implementation over time. With a public field, the underlying data type must always be the same because calling code depends on the field being the same. However, with a property, you  can change the implementation.