# C# Member variable inheritance

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, member-variables

I'm a little new to C#, but I have a fairly extensive background in programming.

What I'm trying to do: Define different MapTiles for a game. I've defined the base MapTile class like this:

```
public class MapTile
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle mapRectangle;

    public MapTile(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        this.mapRectangle = rectangle;
    }
}
```

I then define a subclass GrassTile like this:

```
class GrassTile : MapTile
{
    new Texture2D texture = Main.GrassTileTexture;
    new public Rectangle mapRectangle;

    public GrassTile(Rectangle rectangle) : base(rectangle)
    {
        this.mapRectangle = rectangle;
    }
}
```

In my Main class I'm creating a new maptile like this:

```
Maptile testTile;
testTile = new GrassTile(new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

However, when I try to render this testTile, its texture ends up being null. My code works fine if I define the texture inside MapTile, so it has nothing to do with my previous implementation of it.

So how can I get GrassTile to be able to modify MapTile's member variable texture? or get my main class to recognize GrassTile's texture instead of MapTile's I fiddled with interfaces as well, but I can't declare interface member variables. Is there something else to C# inheritance that I don't get yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify the reference to Main.GrassTileTexture?  Is that a static property?

Comment: Sorry, its a static property that is working properly when assigned to MapTile, just not to GrassTile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Child class will inherit members of parent class. You don't need to specify them. Also it's better to use properties rather than public fields.

```
public class MapTile
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Rectangle MapRectangle { get; set; }

    public MapTile(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        MapRectangle = rectangle;
    }
}

public class GrassTile : MapTile
{    
    public GrassTile(Rectangle rectangle) : base(rectangle)
    {
        Texture = Main.GrassTileTexture;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Quick question though, property isn't something I can define in C#, I tried "property" and "public property", doesn't show anything.

Also, those { get; set; } blocks aren't necessary, what are they for?

Comment: @Logicon211 property has specific syntax in C# you can read on [msdn about properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Also `{ get; set; }` block is a part of [auto-implemented property definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). And I think it will be very useful for you to read about [difference between public fields and properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5). Sorry didn't respond quickly - was AFK.

Answer (score 2):

You have a little bit of a syntax confusion. "new" keyword can either be used as an operator to instantiate something, as you do in your main, or as a modifier to members to hide inherited members and that's what you're doing in your GrassTile. You're essentially redefining your members there. Correct version might be:

```
   class GrassTile : MapTile
    {
        public GrassTile(Rectangle rectangle) : base(rectangle)
        {
            texture = Main.GrassTileTexture;
        }
    }
```

as your rectangle gets set in the base constructor anyway.

Comment: Another thing is that you should not use static variables like that. C# is said to be pure OOP, and my OOP feeling says that even if you absolutely have to use a static variable, you should do it in the class it logically belongs to. In this case, I'd say it should be MapTile.GrassTexture or GrassTile.Texture

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance make inherited fields persist in derived class.

```
public sealed class GrassTile : MapTile
{
    public GrassTile(Rectangle rectangle) : base(rectangle)
    {
        texture = Main.GrassTileTexture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best here to clarify how you are using the `new` keyword. `new` can be used in two fashions. As an operator and as a modifier.

`new` "Operator"

The new operator is used to create objects and invoke constructors, for example:

```
Class1 MyClass  = new Class1();
```

`new` Modifier

Use the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class. To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class using the same name, and modify it with the new modifier.

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyBaseC 
{
   public int x;
   public void Invoke() {}
}
```

Declaring a member with the name Invoke in a derived class will hide the method Invoke in the base class, that is:

```
public class MyDerivedC : MyBaseC
{
   new public void Invoke() {}
}
```

However, the field x will not be affected because it is not hidden by a similar name.

Name hiding through inheritance takes one of the following forms:

- A constant, field, property, or type introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members with the same name.
- A method introduced in a class or struct hides properties, fields, and types, with the same name, in the base class. It also hides all base class methods with the same signature.
- An indexer introduced in a class or struct hides all base class indexers with the same signature.

Since you are name hiding and declaring a `Maptile` type but initializing to a child `GrassTile` type AND parent `MapTile` type never initialized your `Texture` member is the reason why you seeing a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to improve on in your code;

Firstly, the property `Texture` is already defined in the base class MapTile, so it does not need to be re-defined in the class `GrassTile`; the derived class (GrassTile) inherits this member from the base class (MapTile).

Next, you might consider modifying the base class 'MapTile' to be [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as I presume it has no direct behaviour itself (the texture must be provided by concrete dervied class implemenations).

Then, you can modify the declaration of `texture` to be [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as it should not really be accessed outside the class hierarchy this way. Or else, turn it into a property with `get` and `set` accessors.

Finally, your use of the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx) modifier is incorrect. This modifier is only intended (in this context) to allow you to override a base implementation of some behaviour with a new behaviour (rather than inheriting base behaviour). In this case, you are declaring a 'new' texture in GrassTile, which (is unnecessary) will override the base instance, but ONLY when referenced via the class GrassTile.

```
{
    MapTile m1 = new GrassTile(...);
    //m1.texture == null;
    GrassTile m2 = new GrassTile(...);
    //m2.texture = Main.GrassTileTexture
}
```