# Model abstraction and service design

Tags: model, solid-principles

I'm doing a demo application and I need some guidance to find the best practice.
So I planned to have 2 tables, with the following columns:

```
Table A:
    name
    quantity
    length
    color

Table B:
    name
    quantity
    length
    type
    ingretients
```

I want to build a model structure which extract the common fields into an abstract class. So I planned the following classes:

```
Class abstract X
    name
    quantity
    length

Table A extract X:
    color

Table B extract X:
    type
    ingretients
```

My first question is: Is this a good approach?

Also I planned to design a service which calculates the average lenght of an item (I din't want to use sql queries for this). I was thinking of one service for each class or do one generic service which calculates this value. What do u think, which is the better approach and why?

Comment: While it's usually a good idea to try and reuse code and data, you also have to remember that inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. Is "B" also an "X"? If not then perhaps that's not really a good idea. I also recommend you make it a habit to use classes to encapsulate *behavior* instead of just containers of data. Unless both "A" and "B" share behavior, it's also not a good idea to have them share a common parent. IMO.

Comment: So "X" was created because "A" and "B" classes carried same fields with the the purpose so it seemed a good idea the collect them into a common parent. But in real life these are different things but similar set of attributes.
Could you please share why you think a bad idea to share common parent?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good approach?

In my view, it is ok as you removed variable duplications. Read more here about [member variable inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369232/c-sharp-member-variable-inheritance).

> I was thinking of one service for each class or do one generic service
> which calculates this value. What do u think, which is the better
> approach and why?

If calculations are the same then generic version is better because you will have just one implementation and you will not have duplications of code.