# Why aren't fields serializable

Tags: c#, field, serializable

Why are fields not serializable via the XML serializer, in C#, whereas properties are? I know that properties are actually methods, but I don't see why that should make a difference. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you think that fields are not serializable?

Comment: More than likely either the field is of a data-type that is not yet serializable, or the field is not public.

Comment: Do you have a _specific_ serializer in mind? Like `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `protobuf-net` or something else? The answer would depend on those as it's up to their implementations and designs they wish to include fields, properties, indexers or whatever their intended _usage_ is.

Comment: One of the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0 stated it (sorry I am on my phone and dont have the "share" link) but I can't find any information on it

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: There is only one answer that claims this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/653543/572644. And it has a comment that states that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fields are serializable :

> XML serialization serializes **the public fields and properties of
>   an object**, 
>       or the parameters and return values of methods, into an XML stream that conforms 
>       to a specific XML Schema definition language (XSD) document. 
>       XML serialization results in strongly typed classes with public properties and 
>       fields that are converted to XML. 
>       System.Xml.Serialization contains the classes necessary for serializing 
>       and deserializing XML.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize, initially, that what is and is not serializable could be dependent on the type of serialization

Answer (score 2):

Fields are serializable. In fact, all fields are by default serialized unless you mark them with the `NonSerialized` attribute.

If you talk about XML serialization, then only public fields will be serialized because XML serialization only serializes the public interface of an object.

Comment: Thanks so much! This clarifies a lot.