# Class initialization - Property vs Field

Tags: c#, class, properties, initialization, field

I was wondering what's the best practice for `class initialization`.

One can write:

```
private myClass mc = new myClass();
```

Or:

```
private myClass mc { get; set; }

public Foo()
{
    mc = new myClass();
}
```

I always tend to use it as a `field`. Are there any downsides for using a class as a `property` ? I did some searching on google but none of the results gave me a good answer for this specific question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0)

Comment: A third option is that you can write `private myClass mc; public Foo() { mc = new myClass(); }`

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's private, there's no significant benefit in making it a property. I'd just keep it as a field. I use properties as a way of communicating an API with *other* classes.

Comment: I missed the fact that the property was private as I've never seen anyone do that before. There is definitely no benefits to private properties.

Comment: @DavidArno I deliberately set them to private, because I wanted to know how `class initialization` should be done in a class itself. According to the answers, i'll just stick around with the `field way` :)

Comment: @DeMama Good for you :)

Comment: I'd make it a property if there was some logic, even internal to the class, which should be isolated to the property.  For auto-implemented properties, however, I agree that there's really no tangible benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a property in the second example is unnecessary. You could write it as:

```
private myClass mc;

public Foo()
{
    mc = new myClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties are meant to be getters/setters, which means they provide a part of the mechanism for information hiding. Making them private doesn't do much, as all methods from the class can see private members.

Answer (score 0):

I perefer the first way:

private myClass mc = new myClass();

because:

- private properties has no benefit.
- If you create another constructor, you duplicate the initialization code unless you create some Init method or call this(), which is not as clear as simply initialization the field.