# Adding values from textbox to label

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to know how I would be able to keep adding the values from the textbox to a label, without the label resetting to zero every time I add another Pizza
I basically need code showing me how to add keep adding text box value to a label

```
private void SummaryBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Textbox:the value is shown of the pizza selected
        {

        }

        private void txtPizzaPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        Menu(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{


        private void lblPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Label where the Pizza prices needs to be added up each time I press add pizza
        }

    }
}

//HERE ARE THE PIZZA VALUES

      double PizzaPrice;//Global


 double ExtraTopping;//Global

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CT;



            if (radioButton2.Enabled == true) //PIZZA CHEESE TOMATO
            {
                double ctp = 3.50;
                PizzaPrice = ctp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString(); //Value I want //to add to lblPrice

                CT = radioButton2.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = CT;


            }
            else
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();
            }

        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string VS;

            if (radioButton1.Enabled == true) //PIZZA Veg SUpreme
            {
                double vsp = 5.20;
                PizzaPrice = vsp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString(); //Value I want //to add to lblPrice

                VS = radioButton1.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = VS;

            }
            else
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();
            }

        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SV;


            if (radioButton3.Enabled == true) //PIZZA SPicy Veg
            {
                double svp = 5.20;
                PizzaPrice = svp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString(); //Value I want //to add to lblPrice

                SV = radioButton3.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = SV;


            }
            else
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();  
            }
        }

        private void radioButton6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MF;

            if (radioButton6.Enabled == true) //PIZZA Veg SUpreme
            {
                double mfp = 5.80;
                PizzaPrice = mfp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString(); //Value I want //to add to lblPrice

                MF = radioButton6.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = MF;
            }
            else 
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string HP;

            if (radioButton7.Enabled == true) //PIZZA Ham pineapple
            {
                double hpp = 4.20;
                PizzaPrice = hpp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
                ^ Value I want to add to lblPrice^

                HP = radioButton7.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = HP;

            }
            else
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();

            }
        }

        private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SF;

            if (radioButton4.Enabled == true) // PIZZA Veg SUpreme
            {
                double sfp = 5.60;
                PizzaPrice = sfp;

                txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString(); //Value I want //to add to lblPrice

                SF = radioButton4.Text;

                SummaryBox.Text = SF;

            }
            else
            {
                SummaryBox.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: A hint that may help in the future: your urgency is (1) nothing special and (2) not going to win you any points. Your best bet for getting a fast response is to formulate a very-clear, well-stated, high-quality question.

Comment: You have some copy paste errors in your code here.  Can you clean that up a bit with a focus on narrowing down exactly where you are having a problem?

Comment: ok, I basically need to add a value from a text box to a label, then when I click on the button again, I wanted to textbox value added to the label without it resetting to 0/textbox value, I want to keep on adding the textbox value to the label

Comment: Sorry about the messy code

Comment: Is it `txtPizzaPrice` you are trying to add to? or `SummaryBox`?

Comment: Trying to add "txtPizzaPrice"

Comment: txtPizzaPrice   @paqogomez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is to add a value to `PizzaPrice`, then display it on `txtPizzaPrice.Text` with the £ sign appended to the front.

`PizzaPrice` should be a [property rather than a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0).

```
public double PizzaPrice { get; set; }
```

Notice that I `+=` the value to pizza price, then display it on the text property:

```
private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton7.Checked)
    {
        double hpp = 4.20;
        PizzaPrice += hpp;
        txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
        SummaryBox.Text = radioButton7.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        SummaryBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

You could do a lot to shorten your code.  Try adding the pizza type to the `Tag` of the radio button, and using a struct for your pizza values.  But I'll leave that to you.