# Adding to list C#

Tags: c#, list

Getting errors when I am trying to save my inputs from textboxes to a list. 
I am using visual studio and a windows form application. 
What I want to do is to save the inputs from the textboxes to a list and then display the list in other forms. 
I have created one class with this code:

```
public class myClass
{
    public List<customer> customerIdInfo= new List<customer>();

    public class customer
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
        int phoneNumber { get; set; }
        string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I have this in my form with the textboxes:

```
private void nextForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form1= new Form2(); 

        Form1.Show();

        class myClass= new myClass();
        customerIdInfo.Add(new customer{
                Id = txtCustomerId.Text;
                phoneNumber = txtPhonenumber.Text;
                message = txtMessage.Text;
         });
```

All the code in the form with the textboxes gets error messages anyone knowws how I can solve this problem?

Comment: class myClass= new myClass(); ???

Comment: Form2 Form1= new Form2() ???

Comment: I am not sure how to write that but don't I have to write something like that to get the list and info from the other class. It might have to have different names like: 
class myClassA = new myClass();

Comment: You are storing `txtPhoneNumber` as `int` but it is actually `string`.

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Please update your question with error messages, otherwise we can guess a lot..

Comment: Form2 Form1 = new Form2() is to get to the next form in the program

Comment: Okay I will change it to a string but it doesn't solve all the problems.
I get alot of diffferent errors some of them is: 
Invalid expression term 'class'
;expected
syntax error ;; expected

Comment: You can solve the problem by reading and understanding the error messages. If you don't know what they mean, google them...

Comment: aren't object initializers expected to separate property assignments using commas, not semi-colons? (apart from the obvious mistakes that have been pointed out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were quite some errors in your original code. I have fixed them and commented on them, but Stack Overflow requires a certain level of understanding. Try to pick up a good C# book or read MSDN, so you can learn what the expected syntax is and how you can interpret compiler errors. This isn't exactly the last time you'll get them.

```
class myClass= new myClass();
```

You can only use [`class` to declare a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx). Here you [declare a variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742(v=vs.71).aspx), which is done by naming its type or [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

```
myClass myClass = new myClass();
// Or
var myClass = new myClass();
```

Then in your [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
new customer 
{
    Id = txtCustomerId.Text;
    phoneNumber = txtPhonenumber.Text;
    message = txtMessage.Text;
}
```

You use semicolons (`;`) where commas should be used (`,`):

```
new customer 
{
    Id = txtCustomerId.Text,
    phoneNumber = txtPhonenumber.Text,
    message = txtMessage.Text,
}
```

And you try to assign a `string` to an `int`:

```
phoneNumber = txtPhonenumber.Text
```

Which you can't do, it [needs to be parsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx):

```
phoneNumber = int.Parse(txtPhonenumber.Text)
```

You will also need to add error checking, because users can type in things that can't be parsed to an integer.

Then you try to access a variable named `customerIdInfo` in order to `Add()` a new customer, but that variable doesn't exist:

```
customerIdInfo.Add(...);
```

You want the field of the `myClass` instance:

```
myClass.customerIdInfo.Add(...);
```

And consider [making it a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) and [naming things properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I will take your recommendation and read and try from a good C# book and watch  more tutorials.

Comment: @user you should do that, but don't get too focused on reading and watching, you need to code to practice.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that my plan is to watch tutorials and read from books that take up the same things in C# and code at the same time. Then go on to a new part in coding. Thank you very much for your tips @CodeCaster do you have any tips on any good books in C#?

Comment: @user I'm sorry, I don't have any concrete titles for you as I'm not familiar with your level of expertise and specific interests, but you I encourage you to just type "C#" on a site that sells books and find a book that matches your interests and level of expertise. Be sure to read the reviews, many say whether they found it easy as a beginner's book or steep to learn instead.

Comment: I want to thank you so much for all of your help. I have found a couple of books and now it is time to become a master of coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a reserved word in C# used for defining a class, it can't be used to declare a variable. So the line `class myClass = new myClass()` won't compile, you want

```
myClass obj = new myClass();
```

Or if you are using C# 3.0 or later you can use the `var` keyword i.e.

```
var obj = new myClass();
```

With C# you shouldn't use Pascal casing for variables i.e. `Form1`, use camel casing

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
```

Also, `customer` is a *nested* class (not sure if that's deliberate) so unless your `new customer` code is arguably breaking the design here. Sounds like what you really want is something like

```
myClass obj = new myClass();
obj.AddNew("CustomerId", 01234567, "Some message");
```

FYI - telephone number as `int` is not a great idea, means you can't store values like `+44 01234 56789` or `(0)141 232-4334` etc.

Comment: Thanks I have changed to this now but I still get a lot of errors :(

Comment: @user3076791 that's because there are a lot of errors in your code. You should really go and read a book on C# because a lot of the issues you have are basic syntax errors.

Comment: Okay thanks I will do that. Might be the big problem when I am learning by myself I think I can do more than I really can so best to study harder :)