# Attribute.IsDefined always returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, attributes

I am trying to check if a variable has a TextArea attribute, but even if it does it still returns false.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class Product
{
    [SerializeField] string ID;
    [SerializeField] string Name;
    [TextArea(4, 8)]
    [SerializeField] string Description;
    [SerializeField] double Price;
}

Product product;

public void GetProperties()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = product.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        Debug.Log(Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(TextAreaAttribute)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate, but this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0

Comment: Yeah it's okay, just figured it out. I use GetProperties(), but I need to use GetFields() instead.Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use GetFields() rather than GetProperties().

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `TextArea` is a field. You should use something like this:

```
var fieldsWithTextAreaAttribute = typeof(Product)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<TextAreaAttribute>() != null)
    .ToList();
```

This will give you all fields annotated with `TextArea`. Then you can write `GetFields()` like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public List<FieldInfo> GetFieldsWithTextArea()
{
    return typeof(Product)
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<TextAreaAttribute>() != null)
        .ToList();
}
```