# C# Custom field, data type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to create a custom field in dot.net core which will have a bool as well as an integer or string value, something like the following:

```
Public MyCustomField field;
field.BoolValue = true or false;
field.NumberValue = 101;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You want a structure or class with multiple fields/properties of its own? Or a field/property you can assign a value of different types to?

Comment: What do you mean by Field ...in dot net you can create your custom types by many ways (classes, structs, Records) !!

Comment: There is no `Public` modifier in c#. Did you mean `public`?

Comment: @IbramReda There is a question here that will help you understand what a field is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0

Comment: I need a field/property I can assign a value of different types to.

Comment: @RufusL I already know the difference between properties and field, but the Way of Question is confusing me, anyway thanks for sharing I enjoy reading it, you are lighting me 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
void Main()
{
    field.BoolValue = true;
    field.NumberValue = 101;
}

public MyCustomField field;

public struct MyCustomField // or `class`
{
    public bool BoolValue;
    public int NumberValue;
}
```