# Is it possible to not write `public` each time before a field in a block of public fields?

Tags: c#, field, access-modifiers

I have a class with many fields and about half of them are public. Right now it looks like this:

```
public int someint1, someint2, someint3;
public string str1, str2;
public bool[] boolArray;
public List<string> listOfStrings;
```

…and so on. And after that there are some private fields.

Is it possible to write `public` just once for all those public fields?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You could, however, define a custom object that has the desired fields on it with standard getters/setters, and then you could reduce the section to something like `public CustomObj state;`

Comment: Fields should never be public though (except possibly readonly fields). It’s a simple rule, don’t deviate from it unless there’s a good reason.

Comment: @KonradRudolph why, what's bad in using public fields?

Comment: @user1306322 - The answer to that is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480627/why-wont-anyone-accept-public-fields-in-c

Comment: @user1306322 Check out [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields) and its duplicate for the gory details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that in `C#`, you have to declare for *every* field its access way.
In general `C#` tends limit access *by-default*, so even if *do not write anything*, the members will end up like `private` ones.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, and you should think about using properties rather than public fields - [Why won't anyone accept public fields in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480627/why-wont-anyone-accept-public-fields-in-c)

Comment: And then, as a next step, get rid of the properties, too. They also expose the state publicly. [Tell, don’t ask](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont declare an access modifier (private, protected, internal, public), the code will take is a private (so most protected one).
Else, you have to delclare it by your self, so type the one you need!