# Knockout.js - Update page every 5 seconds with new value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am just looking into knockout.js with MVC-Web-API and I am trying to create a Hello World page that will update the time on the page every 5 seconds. It is making the call every 5 seconds, I can see this in my controller (breakpoint), but still nothing displays on screen.

UPDATE:
I have still been working on this, and I have now established that I am getting the data back from the server, the call is being made to the controller every 5 seconds, and it is returning the JSON I need (alerts are showing this) however there is still nothing displaying on the span element on the page.

I realistically need to use the mapping function as I am developing a larger website, that has a model with over 50 properties and don't particularly want to go through and map them individually to in the viewmodel.

I have included my code below.

```
<span data-bind="text: TimeString"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;
var getUpdates = setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON(
        "/Values/Get", {},
        function (model) {
            alert(model.TimeString);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(model, viewModel);
        });
}, 5000);

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON(
            "/Values/Get", {},
            function (model) {
                var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
                alert(model.TimeString);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            });
    });

function bindViewModel(model) {
    ko.applyBindings(model);
}
```

```
public class HelloWorldModel
{
    public DateTime TimeDT { get; set; }
    public String TimeString { get; set; }
}

    public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public HelloWorldModel Model = new HelloWorldModel();

    [System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        Model.TimeDT = DateTime.Now;
        Model.TimeString = Model.TimeDT.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        return Json(Model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `data` in your binding? Is it a custom binding? Or you've meant `<span data-bind="text: TimeString"></span>`?

Comment: Where is the updateFromJSON coming from? In the documentation, it states `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);`

Comment: You should be using the mapping plugin in your original AJAX call, not just the one that repeats every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), it shouldn't be too hard. In your first call to the server, do:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You are applying bindings with a JS object (getJSON returns a JS object, not a JSON string, if I'm correctly reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)).

After that, in your repeated function, do:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(model, viewModel);
```

From the documentation:

> - All properties of an object are converted into an observable. If an update would change the value, it will update the observable.
> - Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate add/remove
>     actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as the original
>     JavaScript array.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need replace the complete view-model and can instead update the properties returned from your Ajax request, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var vm = {
        TimeDT: ko.observable(),
        TimeString: ko.observable()
    };

    function updateValues() {    
        $.getJSON("/Values/Get").done(function(data) {
            vm.TimeDT(data.TimeDT);
            vm.TimeString(data.TimeString);
        });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    updateValues();
    setInterval(updateValues, 5000);
});
```

You can see here a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/CTeyT/) I made in JsFiddle.

Comment: It's true he doesn't need to completely replace the viewmodel. But with this solution, you're doing all the work yourself again. The nice thing about the KO mapping plugin is that is does that for you. The first time (when creating the viewmodel), but also later, when you want to update your viewmodel. It will update all observables for you (with `ko.mapping.fromJS(model, viewModel);`). This is interesting when you have several observable properties, and when you add properties over time.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you too. In that case, I would make his current ViewModel a property of a more complex (composed?) ViewModel. The answer I posted is effective for simple scenarios like the one Ben posted in his example.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work with Ben.

There are a few issues with the code, the first is you are missing some javascript references,  secondly the viewModel object is always null each time the timer loops through.

You need to download the knockout mapping Javascript file from [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js), name it knockout.mapping-latest.js and save it in the Scripts directory. Then make sure the references to jquery and knockout.js are added.

An updated Razor view is below:

```
<div id="body">

    <span data-bind='text: TimeString'></span>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModel;
        var getUpdates = setInterval(function () {
            $.getJSON(
                "/Values/Get", {},
                function (model) {
                    //alert(model.TimeString);
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(model, viewModel);
                });
        }, 5000);

        var viewModelSet = false;

        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $.getJSON(
                    "/Values/Get", {},
                    function (model) {
                        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
                        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                    });
            });

        function bindViewModel(model) {
            ko.applyBindings(model);
        }
    </script>    

</div>
```

Just to add, public fields in a class are generally a no-go, in your ViewModel your HelloWorldModel instance doesn't get accessed from anywhere else in the code, just from within that class so it can be private. If it was accessed from elsewhere, the best practise would be to keep it private, and expose it through a property. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480627/969613).