# Trying to consume Web Service class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to consume a webservice class called "Member". localhost is a web reference for the webservice "Authenticate". I'm creating a login page using a login control in ASP.NET. This piece of code is in the login routine. Can you give me a hint please? I want the login control to read the string that the webservice returns so that I can check if the user is authenticated or not. if it returns "noaccess" then the person cant access protected pages. Thank you :)

```
protected void lgnMemeber_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
 try {
   string emailAddress = lgnMemeber.UserName;
   string userPassword = lgnMemeber.Password;
   localhost.Member memb = new localhost.Member();
   localhost.Authenticate auth = new localhost.Authenticate();
   string authReturn=auth.Authenticatee(emailAddress, userPassword).ToString();
   lblError.Text = emailAddress; lblError.Text += userPassword; lblError.Text += authReturn;

  //string access = "noaccess";
  // if (authReturn.Contains(access))
  //{
      // e.Authenticated = false;
  //}
  //else
  //{
    // e.Authenticated = true;
  //}

 }
 catch(Exception ex) {
    lblError.Text += ex.Message;
 }
 }
```

Here is my webService:

```
/// <summary>
/// Member class
/// </summary>
public class Member
{

    public string accessLevel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Member constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Member()
    {
        accessLevel = "noaccess";
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// HASC Authentication Web Service
/// </summary>
[WebService(Description = "Hamilton Adult Soccer Club (HASC) Authentication Web          Service.", Namespace = "http://mohawkcollege.ca/hasc")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Authenticate : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public Authenticate () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Take the email and password of the user. If user exists, it returns the access   level and the PesronID of that member
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Email">Email of the member</param>
    /// <param name="Password">Password of the member to authenticate</param>
    /// <returns>Access level and PersonID of authenticated member</returns>
    [WebMethod(Description = "<ul><li>Accepts 2 string parameters, Email and Password.</li><li>Returns a string indicating access level and the PersonID of the authenticated club member</li></ul>")]
    public Member Authenticatee(string Email, string Password)
    {
        Member member = new Member();

        string con_string = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HASCConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PersonID, Email, UserPassword, Player, Coach, Referee, Administrator FROM Persons WHERE Email='" + Email+"' AND UserPassword='"+Password+"'", con);

        try
        {
            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    int personID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    bool player = reader.GetBoolean(3);
                    bool coach = reader.GetBoolean(4);
                    bool referee =reader.GetBoolean(5);
                    bool admin = reader.GetBoolean(6);

                   if (Email == reader.GetString(1) && Password==reader.GetString(2))
                   {       
                       if (player) { 
                           member.accessLevel = "player,"+personID; 
                       } 
                       else if(coach) { 
                           member.accessLevel = "coach,"+personID;
                       }
                       else if (referee)
                       {
                           member.accessLevel = "referee,"+personID;
                       }
                       else if (admin)
                       {
                           member.accessLevel = "admin,"+personID;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           member.accessLevel = "accessapproved";
                       }
                   }                 
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            member.accessLevel = "noaccess";
        }

        return member;
    }
}
```

Comment: Method _Authenticatee()_ returns an instance of _Member_ class, which string are you referring to?

Comment: I want to check if the user is authenticated or not. if it returns "noaccess" then the person cant access protected pages

Comment: @Fruits - is the intention is to call the service from client, and service be able to authenticate, or you already got the authenticate object and just want to check its accesslevel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
string authReturn=auth.Authenticatee(emailAddress, userPassword).ToString();
```

To this:

```
string authReturn = auth.Authenticatee(emailAddress, userPassword).accessLevel;
```

Or... Override the ToString method in your Member class:

```
public class Member
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return accessLevel;
    }
}
```

By the way, the recommendation is not to use public fields (like accessLevel): make it private, or use a public property instead: [Why won't anyone accept public fields in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480627/why-wont-anyone-accept-public-fields-in-c)