# how to convert datetime? to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have filed `txtb_dateOfService` is required to complete the form but if `txtb_dateOfService` is emapty return null if not  TryParse the date `>` I had this error I don't know how to fix it

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some
>   invalid arguments

```
    DateTime? dateOfService= null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtb_dateOfService.Text))
    {
        dateOfService = null;

    }
    else
        if (DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out dateOfService))
        {

        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the nullable in the first place? This code looks like it could very easily be rewritten without nullables.

Comment: You can also use the ?? operator in C# to "dereference" a nullable (and provide a default value if the nullable is in fact null).

Comment: What do you want to do if `txtb_dateOfService.Text` is not empty but not a valid (parseable) date/time value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass a reference to `DateTime?` into a method expecting `DateTime`. You can solve this by introducing a temporary variable, like this:

```
else { // <<=== This is the final "else" from your code
    DateTime tmp;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out tmp))
    {
        dateOfService = tmp;
    } else {
        dateOfService = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `dateOfService.Value = tmp`?

Comment: @JoelEtherton C# takes care of this automatically.

Comment: This will not work, check my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg It looks like it did work for the OP, no?

Comment: It is actually not necessary to test for null or empty before. `TryParse` will handle these cases automatically by returning `false` and does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is converting `DateTime?` to `DateTime`, not vice versa. The `DateTime.TryParse` method's `out` parameter is not nullable; in the event `TryParse` fails the out parameter will be assigned `DateTime.MinValue` as its value. There is no reason to declare your `dateOfService` variable as a nullable type from this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can either throw an exception if the parse fails:

```
DateTime? dateOfService= null;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtb_dateOfService.Text))
{
    dateOfService = null;
}
else
{
    // will throw an exception if the text is not parseable
    dateOfService = DateTime.Parse(txtb_dateOfService.Text);  
}
```

or use an intermediate DateTime to store the parsed result:

```
DateTime? dateOfService= null;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtb_dateOfService.Text))
{
    dateOfService = null;

}
else
{
    DateTime temp;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out temp))
    {
        dateOfService = temp;
    } 
    else 
    {
        dateOfService = null;
    }
}
```

Either of these can be logically simplified; I'm showing the full breakout to convey the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your `string` in a `DateTime`

```
DateTime? dataOfService = null;
DateTime output;

if (DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out output))
   dataOfService = output;
```

now you can use `dataOfService` as a `Nullable<DateTime>` and check if it has a valid data converted using `HasValue` and `Value` properties.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a temp value to hold the out parameter of `TryParse`:

```
DateTime tmp;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out tmp)) {
    dateOfService = tmp;
} else{
    dateOfService = null;
}
```

A more terse example

```
DateTime tmp;
DateTime? dateOfService = DateTime.TryParse(txtb_dateOfService.Text, out tmp)
   ? tmp
   : (DateTime?)null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try out dateOfService.Value, this should work (I think)

Comment: You can't pass properties as an out parameter, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370238/passing-a-property-as-an-out-parameter-in-c-sharp