# Using out parameter on class property

Tags: c#, properties, parameters, parameter-passing, out

Is there a way to use `out` on uninitialized object properties?

Ex:

```
QuoteDetail q = new QuoteDetail();

Dictionary<int, string> messageDict = SplitMessage(msg);

messageDict.TryGetValue(8, out q.QuoteID); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do that. Just use a temporary variable instead:

```
QuoteDetail q = new QuoteDetail();

Dictionary<int, string> messageDict = SplitMessage(msg);
string quoteID;
if (messageDict.TryGetValue(8, out quoteID))
{
    q.QuoteID = quoteID;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: NO

You can't use properties. You will have to use a variable instead

BTW: has been answered a dozen times already:
[Passing a property as an 'out' parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370238/passing-a-property-as-an-out-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate the out parameter.

The following link from msdn should help...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx