# Is it good practice to wrap trivial functions in wrappers?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a code review and I've noticed that the developer has done this:

```
UserSession.LocationId = CheckInteger(elementValue);
```

with this wrapper

```
    private int CheckInteger(string elementValue)
    {
        int outNumber;
        int.TryParse(elementValue, out outNumber);
        return outNumber;
    }
```

I can't see that this brings very much to the party.  Should I push back, or just let sleeping dogs lie?  I don't think there's any particular company policy that covers this.

Comment: It hides the hideous `out` parameter. I'd let it be.

Comment: depends, could having an invalid `elementValue` being turned into null be a bad thing or is it something that should be handled better?

Comment: The appropriate site for such questions is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Personally, I'd rather they do this: `int.TryParse(elementValue, UserSession.LocationId)` unless the rules for checking integers are likely to change.

Comment: If it repeats a lot, maybe it would be better to move it to a extension methods. But it's ok to keep with that

Comment: @DanielCook 's comment should be the answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, it isn't.  Not at all.  That's not the OP's code, for a start.  It's also just a tiny code snippet.  Completely off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @itsbruce they're the maintainer of the code. However, I think this question might be too opinion-based even for CR. There's also very little context here. CR loves context.

Comment: i think http://programmers.stackexchange.com is where this question should really be

Comment: Sorry if I've contravened the rules!

Comment: @DanielCook if `LocationId` is a property (as it should be) then you cannot pass it as an `out` parameter.

Comment: @juharr Good to know. Unfortunately, my work environment is fairly anti-properties(for no good reason), so I'd never had an occasion to experience that. I just tested this in VB.Net and it certainly works with properties. However... C# may be throwing you into the pit of success. :-) Cheers

Comment: As an interesting note, [Jon Skeet recommended a helper function like this in an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1370256/1316573), but his was static.

Comment: @user1666620 when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 9):

Are they sleeping dogs or wolves? This code effectively discards non-integer values and returns 0 for failed cases.

This may or may not be appropriate, but the name certainly is misleading - no check is performed at all. Errors are simply discarded. It's almost equivalent to hiding exceptions.

This *can* hurt you when invalid values aren't detected and 0s are set in unexpected places.

Such a method should at *least* be renamed to `GetIntegerOrDefault` so it's explicit that it will return a default value on error.

You should also ensure that 0 is a valid value for LocationId or at least an expected default. Otherwise you may encounter some very hard to diagnose bugs.

I've encountered bugs in a Stock Exchange application that send portfolio performance ratios of -100%, because someone 10 levels bellow decided to return 0 on invalid exchange rate values, and nobody remembered 5 years later.

Answer (score -1):

Given that you could just, in this case, write `int.TryParse(elementValue, out UserSession.LocationId)` I would say this is not a good idea.

Now, if you needed to add logging to it or deal with special cases/errors in a consistent way, then sure go for it.

Comment: `LocationId` looks like a property, and I don't think you can pass a property as an `out` parameter.

Comment: Good point... I just tested it and for properties no you cannot. Member vars you can, but `A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter`