# List/Collection of references to Properties

Tags: c#, list, properties, containers, indexer

Consider these properties,

```
        double _temperature;
        public double Temperature
        {
            get { return _temperature; }
            set { _temperature = value; }
        }
        double _humidity;
        public double Humidity
        {
            get { return _humidity; }
            set { _humidity = value; }
        }
        bool _isRaining;
        public bool IsRaining
        {
            get { return _isRaining; }
            set { _isRaining = value; }
        }
```

And now I want to make a list/collection/container of properties like this,

```
PropertyContainer.Add(Temperature);  //Line1
PropertyContainer.Add(Humidity);     //Line2
PropertyContainer.Add(IsRaining);    //Line3
```

I want to make this such that later on I may be able to access the **current** values of properties using *index*, something like this,

```
object currentTemperature =  PropertyContainer[0];
object currentHumidity    =  PropertyContainer[1];
object currentIsRaining   =  PropertyContainer[2];
```

But obviously, this is not going to work, since `PropertyContainer[0]` will return the old value - the value which `Temperature` had at the time of adding `Temperature` to the container (see the `Line1` above).

Is there any solution to this problem? Basically I want to access *current* values of properties *uniformly*; the only thing that can change is, the index. The index however could be string as well.

PS: I don't want to use Reflection!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you could use Lambdas:

```
List<Func<object>> PropertyAccessors = new List<Func<object>>();
PropertyAccessors.Add(() => this.Temperature);
PropertyAccessors.Add(() => this.Humidity);
PropertyAccessors.Add(() => this.IsRaining);
```

then you could to this:

```
object currentTemperature = PropertyAccessors[0]();
```

Comment: this is awesome solution. after I posted the question, I got the same solution from [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/c-passing-properties-by-reference). thanks a lot for the quick response with this awesome trick!

Comment: Oops, I forgot that. Actually before it was asking me to wait 5 minutes, God knows why. Anyway, answer accepted and +1 from me.