# Lambda expressions / delegate assign variable

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Actually I can not even say exactly how that thing is called correctly but I need something that can assign variables / properties / fields in one method. I will try to explain...
I have the following code:

```
txtBox.Text = SectionKeyName1; //this is string property of control or of any other type
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName1))
{
    string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName1);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
    {
        txtBox.Text = translation;
    }
}

stringField = SectionKeyName2; //this is class scope string field
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName2))
{
    string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName2);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
    {
        stringField = translation;
    }
}

stringVariable = SectionKeyName3; //this is method scope string variable
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName3))
{
    string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName3);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
    {
        stringVariable = translation;
    }
}
```

As I see, this code can be refactored to one method, that receives the "object" to set and SectionKeyName. So it can be something like:

```
public void Translate(ref target, string SectionKeyName)
{
    target = SectionKeyName;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName))
    {
        string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
        {
            target = translation;
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT**: I will can not use that method in case when I want to assign texBox.Text, since properties can not be passed byref....
[I found topic on SO where is solution for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/passing-properties-by-reference-in-c-sharp), but it solves the properties and I stuck with fields / variables....

Please help me to find the way to write a single method that will handle all of my cases...

```
//This method will work to by varFieldProp = Translate(SectionKeyName, SectionKeyName), but would like to see how to do it with Lambda Expressions.
public string Translate(string SectionKeyName, string DefaultValue)
{
    string res = DefaultValue; //this is string property of control or of any other type
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName))
    {
        string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
        {
            res = translation;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: "but would like to see how to do it with Lambda Expressions" - that will not be an improvement. Just use that last function variant. It's simple and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
public void Translate(Action<string> assignToTarget, string SectionKeyName)
        {
            assignToTarget(SectionKeyName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionKeyName))
            {
                string translation = Translator.Translate(SectionKeyName);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
                {
                    assignToTarget(translation);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it would be **better** if you simply remove the lambda and let the function returns the translated string to use when needed. Just for completeness, to call this function you can use:

```
Translate(k=>textBox1.Text=k,sectionKeyName);
```

Comment: I think I will use the simple function that returns the string, but for my education, can you show me how I would call the function with Action<string>? Thanks !