# Using ref on Properties

Tags: c#, properties, ref

I have a class Items

```
public class Items
{
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public int B1 { get; set; }
    //...
    public int A9 { get; set; }
    public int B9 { get; set; }
}
```

and i have to compare properties (`A1` and `B1`, `A2` and `B2` and so on)

in case that `Bx > Ax` i need to swap them - here is my method:

```
public static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        int Temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = Temp;
    }
}
```

but that way the application doesn't compile:

```
Items i1 = new Items() { A1 = 2010, B1 = 2000 };
Swap(ref i1.A1,ref  i1.B1);
```

Error says that `ref` or `out` can't be used on properties. is there a better/cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/passing-properties-by-reference-in-c-sharp

Comment: `int` is a value type anyway, why are you passing by ref?

Comment: int a1 = i1.A1;
int b1 = i1.B1
Swap(ref a1,ref  b1);