# How to modify different boolean properties with one method within C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, action, func

I am currently facing the following problem with a `Menu Strip` containing several different settings such as:

- Show X
- Show Y
- Show Z

All those items have corresponding properties of the type `bool`, because those variables are also passed to other classes. Currently, when I click on "Show Y", I have a dedicated function called `HandleShowY()` which toggles the `bool` and the checkmark within the Menu Strip Item.

A new method for every newly added property seems like a huge code smell to me and requires a ton of added overhead for each new property. Thus, I came up with the idea to make a generic `HandleMenuStripItemBool()` which receives the property and the menu item by reference, such that only one method exists to handle this type of behaviour.

Unfortunately, I am running into problems while trying to pass my `bool` property to this method by reference, my knowledge of `action`, `func` and `delegate` has mostly faded away and only confuses me more and more after every new tutorial I read.

Example code:

```
// different properties of type bool, defined in form1
private bool ShowX { get; set; }
private bool ShowY { get; set; }

// generic menu strip item bool handler
private void HandleMenuStripItemBool(bool boolProp, ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
{
    // toggle bool depending on current value
    // add check mark to or remove check mark from ToolStripMenuItem
}

// click event of the "Show X" menu strip item, defined in form1
private void showXToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleMenuStripItemBool(ShowX, showXToolStripMenuItem);
}

// click event of the "Show Y" menu strip item, defined in form1
private void showYToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleMenuStripItemBool(ShowY, showYToolStripMenuItem);
}
```

TL;DR: what is the best way to create a method which receives a property of the type `bool` by reference, in such a way that the method can be reused for several other properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If would be great if you can show us some code.

Comment: You're right, I have added an example.

Comment: why do you need the bools if your menu item is checked? can't you just do `private bool ShowX { get { return showXToolStripMenuItem.Checked; }  set {  showXToolStripMenuItem.Checked = value; } }` ?

Comment: Wow, neat solution! This is working and while being slightly different from what I had in mind, a way better solution. Do you mind reposting your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: thanks, added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not specifically answering how to pass the bool property by reference, why not just use the `Checked` value of the menu item, in which case you won't need to maintain the value of the bool property, and will only have a single source of truth

```
private bool ShowX 
{ 
     get { return showXToolStripMenuItem.Checked; } 
     set { showXToolStripMenuItem.Checked = value; } 
}
```

Comment: You're right, a very clean solution indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as reference and work on it inside the method:

```
        bool testBool;
        ToggleBoolValue(ref testBool);
        private void ToggleBoolValue(ref bool toggle)
        {
            toggle = !toggle;
            // some other tasks
        }
```

Comment: That's what I have tried before. Unfortunately, because my `ShowX` and `ShowY` variables are `properties`, I cannot pass them by reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/passing-properties-by-reference-in-c-sharp @J.Doe

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're using a very modern version of C# (7.0 or later, I think), then you can make your properties be `ref` returning, and then use `ref` as Michal suggested:

```
using System;

public class Bob
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var b = new Bob();
    b.showYToolStripMenuItem_Click();
    Console.WriteLine(b.ShowY);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  // different properties of type bool, defined in form1
  private ref bool ShowX { get { return ref _showX; } }
  private ref bool ShowY { get { return ref _showY; }  }
  private bool _showX = false;
  private bool _showY = false;

  // generic menu strip item bool handler
  private void HandleMenuStripItemBool(ref bool boolProp)
  {
    boolProp = true;
  }

  // click event of the "Show X" menu strip item, defined in form1
  private void showXToolStripMenuItem_Click()
  {
    HandleMenuStripItemBool(ref ShowX);
  }

  // click event of the "Show Y" menu strip item, defined in form1
  private void showYToolStripMenuItem_Click()
  {
    HandleMenuStripItemBool(ref ShowY);
  }
}
```

(Main added and irrelevant parameters removed to make this a self-contained console demo)