# C#/Entity Framework: How to only call setter, when the value changes?

Tags: entity-framework, function, properties, entity-framework-5, setter

I am writing bugfix code for a legacy ASP.NET application which uses Entity Framework 5. I am taking user input and update my entities using the new data.

My entities do not change much, but still I currently take all values from the UI and set it on the entities like so:

```
myEntityUnit.MyEntityAddress.AddressLine1 = AddressLine1; //Update with potentially the same value
```

This works functionally, but I also causes much of Database traffic, even for the non-changed properties since EF remembers those updates in it's change tracker. The property of the above actually looks like:

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String AddressLine1
    {
        get
        {
            return _AddressLine1;
        }
        set
        {
            OnAddressLine1Changing(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("AddressLine1");
            _AddressLine1 = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true, "AddressLine1");
            ReportPropertyChanged("AddressLine1");
            OnAddressLine1Changed();
        }
    }
```

So, whenever the setter is accessed, even with the same value, a change is detected.

**How to best avoid this, on some (dozens) properties, on some entities only (too keep bugfix changes minimal)?**

I've come up with some simple check conditions like so, but this feels clumsy and overly verbose:

```
if (profilingEnterpriseUnit.ProfilingAddress.AddressLine1 != AddressLine1) {
    profilingEnterpriseUnit.ProfilingAddress.AddressLine1 = AddressLine1;
}
```

**Is there a way to write a function that update a property, via it's setter, only when the value differs using the getter?**

*Note: I have looked into [Passing properties by reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/passing-properties-by-reference-in-c-sharp) but the solution is not using getters at all and still is quite verbose both in usage and code.*

Comment: It says here only the properties marked with isModified = true will be saved to dB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/property-values

Comment: @bestinamir In practice, I experienced DB accesses even when set to the same value. Any access seems to count as "change" here.

Comment: May be you’ll get different result if you upgrade to EF6 which they say backward compatible https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/entity-framework-6-tips

Comment: @bestinamir I would, but since this only a bugfix release, this is out of scope, unfotunately.