# How to update a string property in the Model from an aggregated ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel, composition

I'm working on a GUI application in WPF/MVVM. Let's say i have a Model class which is populated deserializing a (third-party) XML file

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ReservationId { get; set; }
}
```

and a ViewModel which exposes to its View a lot of properties and commands to manipulate the Model, in this case strings (such as ReservationId):

```cs
class StringManipulatorViewModel
{
    string modelString; //here's the problem

    public StringManipulatorViewModel(string modelString) 
    {
        this.modelString = modelString;
    }

    //Stuff to let the view manipulate the string
}
```

StringManipulatorViewModel is highly reusable and it is used by a lot of ViewModels, e.g.

```cs
class PersonViewModel
{
    Person model;
    public StringManipulatorViewModel ReservationManipulatorVM; //aggregated ViewModel
    public StringManipulatorViewModel AddressManipulatorVM; //aggregated ViewModel

    public PersonViewModel(Person model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        ReservationManipulatorVM = new StringManipulatorViewModel(model.ReservationId); //here's the problem
        AddressManipulatorVM = new StringManipulatorViewModel(model.Address); //here's the problem
    }
}
```

Obviously passing the string as "model" to the ViewModel isn't effective, and C# doesn't seem to allow string references as fields.
What is the best/right way to let member ViewModels manipulate the Model when dealing with string types?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to reference a property, not a string field.

But you can pass a delegate to the setter of the property.

If you also change the modelString field to a property, you can call this delegate automatically when the string is changed.

```
class StringManipulatorViewModel
{
    private string modelString
    {
        get { return _modelString; }
        set { _modelString = value; if (SetModelString != null) SetModelString(value); }
    }
    private string _modelString;
    Action<string> SetModelString;

    public StringManipulatorViewModel(string initialValue, Action<string> setModelString)
    {
        this.modelString = initialValue;
        SetModelString = setModelString;
    }
    //Stuff to let the view manipulate the string
}
```

You initiate the StringManipulatorViewModel in PersonViewModel like this:

```
        ReservationManipulatorVM = new StringManipulatorViewModel(model.ReservationId, value => model.ReservationId = value); //here's the problem
```

Here are some other ideas when you want to pass a property.

[Passing properties by reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402803/passing-properties-by-reference-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm while keeping the model update logic inside StringManipulatorViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a "right" way to manipulate the string as a reference inside the `StringManipulatorViewModel`, once you pass the string as a value it has nothing to do with the model.

But a way to legitimately change the `model` string value whenever the `StringManipulatorViewModel` manipulates it, is by raising an `Event` in the view model when it manipulates the string and then add an event handler to update the model with the new value:

```cs
class StringManipulatorViewModel
{
    string modelString;

    public event EventHandler<string> StringManipulated;


    public StringManipulatorViewModel(string modelString) 
    {
        this.modelString = modelString;
    }


    public ManipulateString() 
    {
        // Manipulate the string

        StringManipulated?.Invoke(this, modelString);
    }
    
}
```

And in the `PersonViewModel` constructor:

```cs
class PersonViewModel
{
    Person model;
    public StringManipulatorViewModel ReservationManipulatorVM;
    public StringManipulatorViewModel AddressManipulatorVM;

    public PersonViewModel(Person model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        ReservationManipulatorVM = new StringManipulatorViewModel(model.ReservationId); 
        AddressManipulatorVM = new StringManipulatorViewModel(model.Address);

        ReservationManipulatorVM.StringManipulated += (sender, e) => model.ReservationId = e;
        AddressManipulatorVM.StringManipulated += (sender, e) => model.Address = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Altough very functional, this approach shifts the model update logic outstide the aggregated viewmodel, which is a bit of a problem for my purposes. Anyway I'm already seeing some parts of my code where your approach will be very useful. Thank you!