# How to I convert this manual code into using Enumerable.Range to initialize my multi-dimensional property?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, enumerable

This question is related to the code sample in the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70694640/2287576).

I now have this constructor:

```
public List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>[] StudentItems { get; set; }
public MSAHistoryWeek()
{
    TalkItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Select(x => new MSAHistoryItemTalk()).ToList();
    Teaching = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => string.Empty).ToList();
    StudentItemStudyNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => string.Empty).ToList();
    StudentItemDescriptions = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => string.Empty).ToList();

    StudentItems = new List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>[]
    {
        new List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(),
        new List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(),
        new List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(),
    };

    foreach(var studentitems in StudentItems)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            studentitems.Add(new MSAHistoryItemStudent());
        }
    }
}
```

I can't work out the `Enumerable.Range` approach to pre-create `StudentItems` how I want:

- I want an array of 3 `List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>`.
- I want each of these arrays to have 5 `MSAHistoryItemStudent` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is a relatively low number of lists, you can replace your calls to `new` with a call to `Enumerable.Range`:

```
StudentItems = new 
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new MSAHistoryItemStudent()).ToList(),
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new MSAHistoryItemStudent()).ToList(),
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new MSAHistoryItemStudent()).ToList(),
};
```

Incidentally, if you put this somewhere:

```
public static List<T> MakeN<T>(int n) where T:new()
  => Enumerable.Range(1,n).Select(x => new T()).ToList();
```

Then you can simplify those calls some:

```
TalkItems = MakeN<MSAHistoryItemTalk>(6);
Teaching = new string[3].ToList();

StudentItems = new
{
    MakeN<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(5),
    MakeN<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(5),
    MakeN<MSAHistoryItemStudent>(5),
};
```

And everywhere else you're using `Enumerable.Range.Select.`.

... apart from where you do it to `string` (for which I've given an alternative form).

Comment: Thanks. I have added adopted this approach. I added that `MakeN` as a member of the `MSAHistoryWeek` class.

Comment: Actually, I have reverted to the long hand `Enumerable.Range` approach. When I did it using `MakeN` I was getting null exceptions where I used `XText`. And that call is only used with the `StudentItems` object..  Reverting to your original suggestion works.

Comment: Perhaps `StudentItems = new []` should have been `new List<MSAHistoryItemStudent>[]`?

Comment: My bad, that was indeed a typo to put the `[]` in; I've taken it out as modern c# only needs the type on one side of the `=` and it's not fussy which eg `var x = new List<string>[] {...}` or `List<string>[] x = new {...}` (your property already defines the type in this latter form). Older c# needs it on both. You'll get a syntax error if your c# is too old to understand it)

Answer (score 2):

Just nest another one of those `Enumerable.Range(...)...` calls in the `Select` call.

```
StudentItems =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x =>
        Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(y =>
            new MSAHistoryItemStudent()
        ).ToList()
    ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for that example showing me.