# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for adding a node to a binary tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

My method(s) look(s) like

```
static Node _root = null;

static void AddToTree(int val)
{
    AddToTree(val, ref _root);
}

static void AddToTree(int val, ref Node root)
{
    if(root == null)
        root = new Node() { Val = val };
    Node left = root.Left, right = root.Right;
    if(root.Val > val)
        AddToTree(val, ref left);
    else if(root.Val < val)
        AddToTree(val, ref right);
}
```

and how I see that it's failing is I run

```
    int[] vals = { 2, 1, 5, 3, 8 };
    foreach(int i in vals)
        AddToTree(i);
    Print();
```

which uses

```
static void Print()
{
    if(_root == null)
        return;
    LinkedList<int> vals = new LinkedList<int>();
    Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();
    q.Enqueue(_root);
    while(q.Count > 0)
    {
        Node front = q.Dequeue();
        vals.AddLast(front.Val);
        if(front.Right != null)
            q.Enqueue(front.Right);
        if(front.Left != null)
            q.Enqueue(front.Left);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", vals));
}
```

and the output I see is

> 2

i.e. the first element added and no other elements.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code by placing breakpoints and stepping through it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code sequence does not do what you think it does:

```
Node left = root.Left;
Foo(ref left);
```

You're passing `left` by reference, not `root.Left`. Now when `Foo()` reassigns `left`, only `left` will be affected, not `root.Left`.

Of course you [can't pass properties by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564557/is-it-possible-to-pass-properties-as-out-or-ref-parameters), so the solution would be to reassign `root.Left = left` after `Foo()` returns.